# Visual Studio 2017 blank window, unresponsive

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I've been trying to create a simple C++ game in Visual Studio 2017, but I can't even get a simple black screen. The window comes up white and unresponsive, is anyone able to help? I've been learning from a free course on Udemy, it has been working up until now. My code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const int screenWidth = 800;
    const int screenLength = 600;
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        cout << "SDL init faliure" << endl;
        return 0;

    }
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Particle Fire", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, screenWidth, screenLength, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Delay(100000);

    if (window == NULL) {
        SDL_Quit();
        return 2;
    }
    SDL_Renderer * renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    SDL_Texture * texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC, screenWidth, screenLength);

        if (renderer == NULL) {
            cout << "Could not produce renderer";
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
                SDL_Quit();
            return 3;

        }
    if (texture == NULL) {
        cout << "Could not produce texture";
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
            SDL_Quit();
        return 3;
    }
    Uint32 *buffer = new Uint32[screenWidth*screenLength];
    memset(buffer, 0xFF, screenWidth*screenLength*sizeof(Uint32));
    for (int i=0; i < screenWidth*screenLength; i++) {

        buffer[i = 0xFFFF0000];
    }
    SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, NULL, buffer, screenWidth * sizeof(Uint32));
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    bool quit = false;
    SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, NULL, buffer, screenWidth * sizeof(Uint32));
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,texture , NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_Event event;
    while (!quit) {

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = true;
            } }

    }
    delete buffer;
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

I've tried changing everything, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I dont know sdl, so I am curious: Do you really need all that code to get nothing but a black screen? If thats really the case I would definitely use something else

Comment: @tobi303 It's not SDL, that's the case for almost all C++ libraries.

Comment: @tobi303 the SDL is meant to be low-level so it's normal that it takes a lot of code

Comment: @cdo256 I know qt and the code I need to write there to get a window is nothing comared to this

Comment: What's up with that gigantic `SDL_Delay()` right after `SDL_CreateWindow()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a 100 second delay immediately after you created the window `SDL_Delay(100000);`.

Also, you need to change `buffer[i = 0xFFFF0000]` to `buffer[i] = 0xFFFF0000`. The first only sets `i` and leaves the buffer unchanged. The second makes the pixel yellow.